# stacking linear-gradients correctly in css

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a button and want to cut all corners.

```
#top .avia-slideshow-button {
   background: 
       linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #44834e 0) top left,
       linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 5px, #44834e 0) top right,
       linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 5px, #44834e 0) bottom right,
       linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 5px, #44834e 0) bottom left;
}
```

The Code above only works if one "linear-gradient" is there.

Comment: What does "it works" mean? What are you seeing? Can we see a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you're layering all of them improperly, they will extend to the other corners. You need to adjust their sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients are taking full width/height so they overlap each other, You need to resize each one, And don't forget `no-repeat`.

I changed the colors to make it more visible.

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #834444 0) top left, 
        linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 5px, #4a4483 0) top right, 
        linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 5px, #7a8344 0) bottom right, 
        linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, #44834e 0) bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:50% 50%; 
    /* if only one value is specified it is then copied for all other backgrounds */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to put "background-size: 51% 50%" because otherwise I had a white vertical line in the middle of the element. But it works now. :-)